# Apache Spark Aggregate JSONL DataFrames Grouped By keeping null values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am pretty new to Spark so I might use some help from you.

I have a couple of JSONL files like these in an S3 bucket, each one of them has a field that contains the name of its file (more on that later):

```
{"id": "abc-123-abc", "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Simonis", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file1.jsonl"}
{"id": "def-563-abc", "first_name": "Mary", "last_name": "Culkin", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file1.jsonl"}
{"id": "abc-532-def", "first_name": "James", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file2.jsonl"}
{"id": "abc-445-abc", "first_name": "Fiona", "last_name": "Goodwill", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file3.jsonl"}
{"id": "abc-167-def", "last_name": "Matz", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file4.jsonl"}
{"id": "ghj-134-abc", "first_name": "Adam", "last_name": "Gleason", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file4.jsonl"}
{"id": "abc-523-abc", "first_name": "Phil", "last_name": "Smith", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file4.jsonl"}
{"id": "ghj-823-abc", "first_name": "Jack", "last_name": "Smith", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file5.jsonl"}
{"id": "abc-128-abc", "first_name": "Mary", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl"}
{"id": "abc-124-ghj", "last_name": "Foster", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl"}
{"id": "ghj-133-abc", "first_name": "Julius", "last_name": "Bull", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl"}
{"id": "abc-723-abc", "first_name": "Gareth", "last_name": "Smith", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file7.jsonl"}
```

Since I read all the bucket files in a single dataframe I lose the relationship between the records and the original file, so the needing for that field.

```
df = spark.read.json('s3://bucket/prefix')
```

I do some transformations with an and I obtain an updated dataframe with some fields added in some of them

```
df2 = df.rdd.map(lambda x: my_transformations(x))

{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "abc-123-abc", "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Simonis", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file1.jsonl"}
{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "def-563-abc", "first_name": "Mary", "last_name": "Culkin", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file1.jsonl"}
{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "abc-532-def", "first_name": "James", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file2.jsonl"}
{"id": "abc-445-abc", "first_name": "Fiona", "last_name": "Goodwill", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file3.jsonl"}
{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "abc-167-def", "last_name": "Matz", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file4.jsonl"}
{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "ghj-134-abc", "first_name": "Adam", "last_name": "Gleason", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file4.jsonl"}
{"id": "abc-523-abc", "first_name": "Phil", "last_name": "Smith", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file4.jsonl"}
{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "ghj-823-abc", "first_name": "Jack", "last_name": "Smith", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file5.jsonl"}
{"id": "abc-128-abc", "first_name": "Mary", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl"}
{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "abc-124-ghj", "last_name": "Foster", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl"}
{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "ghj-133-abc", "first_name": "Julius", "last_name": "Bull", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl"}
{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "abc-723-abc", "first_name": "Gareth", "last_name": "Smith", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file7.jsonl"}
```

I then need to regroup them by "s3_original_file"

```
grouped = df2.groupBy(df2.s3_original_file)
```

And since I need to rewrite the files keeping the original association (I can't use df.write.json because I lose that association, I'll do that with `df.foreach()` and boto3 inside the lambda) I accumulate the aggregate data passing the column names except for the grouping column

```
def fetch_columns(dataframe, grouping):
    output = []
    columns = dataframe.columns
    for column in columns:
        if column != grouping:
            output.append(F.collect_list(column).alias(column))
    return output

resultDF = grouped.agg(*fetch_columns(df2, 's3_original_file'))
```

Then I need to save the resulting dataframe Rows as json lines in the specific file which I might do inside the save_back_to_s3 function.

```
resultDF.foreach(lambda x: save_back_to_s3(x))
```

the problem is:
I get an aggregated list of values per column, instead, I would like to have a single column with the list of the rows grouped and nothing takes care of eventual null values, messing up the ordering. I want to preserve eventually null columns to be aware that data does not exist.

```
>>> resultDF.show(20, False)
+------------------------------+----------------+--------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+
|s3_original_file              |additional_field|first_name    |id                                     |last_name             |
+------------------------------+----------------+--------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+
|s3://bucket/prefix/file3.jsonl|[]              |[Fiona]       |[abc-445-abc]                          |[Goodwill]            |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file7.jsonl|[blabla]        |[Gareth]      |[abc-723-abc]                          |[Smith]               |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file5.jsonl|[blabla]        |[Jack]        |[ghj-823-abc]                          |[Smith]               |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file4.jsonl|[blabla, blabla]|[Adam, Phil]  |[abc-167-def, ghj-134-abc, abc-523-abc]|[Matz, Gleason, Smith]|
|s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl|[blabla, blabla]|[Mary, Julius]|[abc-128-abc, abc-124-ghj, ghj-133-abc]|[Foster, Bull]        |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file1.jsonl|[blabla, blabla]|[John, Mary]  |[abc-123-abc, def-563-abc]             |[Simonis, Culkin]     |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file2.jsonl|[blabla]        |[James]       |[abc-532-def]                          |[]                    |
+------------------------------+----------------+--------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Is it possible to have a resulting dataframe like this one instead?

```
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|s3_original_file              |records                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|s3://bucket/prefix/file3.jsonl|{"id": "abc-445-abc", "first_name": "Fiona", "last_name": "Goodwill", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file3.jsonl"}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file7.jsonl|{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "abc-723-abc", "first_name": "Gareth", "last_name": "Smith", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file7.jsonl"}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file5.jsonl|{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "ghj-823-abc", "first_name": "Jack", "last_name": "Smith", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file5.jsonl"}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file4.jsonl|{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "ghj-134-abc", "first_name": "Adam", "last_name": "Gleason", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file4.jsonl"}\n{"id": "abc-523-abc", "first_name": "Phil", "last_name": "Smith", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file4.jsonl"}                                                                                                           |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl|{"id": "abc-128-abc", "first_name": "Mary", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl"}\n{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "abc-124-ghj", "last_name": "Foster", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl"}\n{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "ghj-133-abc", "first_name": "Julius", "last_name": "Bull", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl"}|
|s3://bucket/prefix/file1.jsonl|{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "abc-123-abc", "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Simonis", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file1.jsonl"}\n{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "def-563-abc", "first_name": "Mary", "last_name": "Culkin", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file1.jsonl"}                                                                            |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file2.jsonl|{"additional_field": "blabla", "id": "abc-532-def", "first_name": "James", "s3_original_file": "s3://bucket/prefix/file2.jsonl"}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Or at least, instead of outputting the dictionaries, I might manage it outputting the separated lists, only it the null values are taken into account in the correct index position of course, like:

```
+------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+
|s3_original_file              |additional_field      |first_name          |id                                     |last_name             |
+------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+
|s3://bucket/prefix/file3.jsonl|[null]                |[Fiona]             |[abc-445-abc]                          |[Goodwill]            |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file7.jsonl|[blabla]              |[Gareth]            |[abc-723-abc]                          |[Smith]               |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file5.jsonl|[blabla]              |[Jack]              |[ghj-823-abc]                          |[Smith]               |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file4.jsonl|[blabla, blabla]      |[null, Adam, Phil]  |[abc-167-def, ghj-134-abc, abc-523-abc]|[Matz, Gleason, Smith]|
|s3://bucket/prefix/file6.jsonl|[null, blabla, blabla]|[Mary, null, Julius]|[abc-128-abc, abc-124-ghj, ghj-133-abc]|[null, Foster, Bull]  |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file1.jsonl|[blabla, blabla]      |[John, Mary]        |[abc-123-abc, def-563-abc]             |[Simonis, Culkin]     |
|s3://bucket/prefix/file2.jsonl|[blabla]              |[James]             |[abc-532-def]                          |[null]                |
+------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason for not using `input_file_name()` for the input filename? You can still write using `write.json` to temp folder and partition by `s3_original_file`, then copy from this temps folder to S3 and rename each file depending on the partition folder name.

Comment: Thanks, I partially solved but I'll try this way too!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `struct` column composed of any columns you wish to include and then use the `to_json` function to transform it to a single JSON string for export:

```
scala> val df = Seq((1, "a", Seq("a", "b", "c")), (2, "b", Seq("d", "e", "f"))).toDF("x", "y", "z")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x: int, y: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val df_json = df.select(to_json(struct($"x", $"y", $"z")).as("json_field"))
df_json: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [json_field: string]

scala> df_json.show(false)
+---------------------------------+
|json_field                       |
+---------------------------------+
|{"x":1,"y":"a","z":["a","b","c"]}|
|{"x":2,"y":"b","z":["d","e","f"]}|
+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved this way.
It works, even if I don't think it's the best way to do it since it's painfully slow.

```
# Read S3 bucket into DataFrame and add an input_file Column to store original filename
    df = spark.read.json(path_source_bucket).withColumn("input_file", F.input_file_name())

    # Get an Enriched df2 dataframe
    rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda payload: invoke_aws_lambda(region, payload, source_bucket, destination_bucket))

    # group RDD by output_file
    grouped = rdd.groupBy(lambda x: x.output_file)

    for s3path, records in grouped.collect():
        output_json = ''
        for record in records:
            row_dict = record.asDict()
            del row_dict["output_file"]
            output_json += json.dumps(row_dict) + "\n"
        save_to_s3(region, output_json.rstrip("\n"), s3path, destination_bucket)
```